# System.out.println hazard in Java EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

When I was starting study Java, I was being told not to do System.out.println in Java EE application. However I don't really know what is the reason of not doing so.

I am fully aware that if we really need to print an important, it should be logged using logging framework.

What I really want to ask here : is there any **real hazard** that **System.out.println** make? Does it cause any performance issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's indeed a performance issue. If you dig down into the JDK source code for `System.out` you'll eventually encounter a `synchronized` block on the output stream.

That means that if you put enough println calls in your source code, the entire code base will effectively run single-threaded, because all threads are waiting for the synchronization lock.

There are some statistics involved here, a single call to println *generally* isn't going to bring your entire application to a crawl. The more println calls in your code, the more likely two or more threads will have to wait for eachother.

Answer (score 3):

Within any Java EE application, there are likely multiple applications all running within the same JVM.  There is only one `System.out`.  If several applications are trying to write to `System.out` at the same time, it can cause contention on the output, and could theoretically impact performance.

Additionally, while not necessarily performance related, it makes the output very messy and difficult to read - especially if multiple applications are writing output at the same time, without any indication as to which application the output is coming from.  (The same for multiple concurrent requests within even the same application.)

As you mentioned, using a proper logging framework will eliminate both these issues.

Answer (score 0):

One more point, whatever written with sysout will be there at runtime, you can't control it, it will print always. By using Logging framework you can turn on/off to logging.